# PyQt transparency error : How can I sovle this problem?

Tags: raspberry-pi, pyqt

I'd like to use PyQt from Raspberry Pi.

On the computer, on the pycharm.

```
self.setStyleSheet("background:transparent")
self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

If you enter it like this, transparency can be applied. With Opacity in Qt desinger ui, the background can be transparent and the widget can be set in the same way as translucent.

However, for the same code, Raspberry Pi does not remove transparency and creates a black background.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=254790

To solve this problem, I looked up graphic driver settings and looked up various ways like the link above, but I couldn't find a reason why it wasn't only available in Raspberry Pi. I need your help. ㅠ

Comment: According to that thread, it's still a bit tricky to get transparency pi *in any case*, so the issue is not related to PyQt.

Comment: If this is not a Qt issue, is it impossible to use transparency in pi?
Or is it not impossible, but are the conditions tricky?